# Is there any difference in meaning/usage/etc between the words 'explorative' and 'exploratory'?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, adjectives, synonyms

#### The question:

I am curious about the relation between the words 'explorative' and 'exploratory'. Are those exact synonyms, or is there a difference in their meaning, their usage, their geographic occurrence, etc?

#### Own attempt:

The way Longman DCE (5th ed) defines 'exploratory' suggests to me that it can only be used to describe *actions*:

> *adj* done in order to find out more about something: *He's going to have an exploratory surgery on his knee.*

(Longman DCE does not contain 'explorative'.) However, the Macquarie Dictionary (7th ed) defines 'exploratory' as:

> *adj.* **1.** relating to or concerned with exploration. **2.** inclined to make explorations. Also, **explorative**.

The first meaning in Macquarie is similar to the one in Longman, but does not appear to be restricted to describe *actions*. The second meaning in Macquarie seems useful to describe *living beings* (or possibly *animate objects*). I am not sure that my interpretation is correct here. I also am not sure whether the crucial 'Also, **explorative**.' at the end concerns both meanings or just the second one.

Comment: If there is a difference I suspect that it might relate to the the degree of uncertainty regarding the outcome. I've never heard of "explorative questioning" or "an explorative medical operation" for instance and in both cases the people performing the action have a good idea what they're looking for.

Comment: @BoldBen: Interesting thought. But if 'explorative' is only used for living beings, as hinted at in the question, that would explain the two examples you provided. Can you think of an example which *is not* explained by the distinction between animage/inanimate, but which *is* explained by the uncertainty of the outcome?

Comment: @MårtenW I don't see what, in your question or any of your references, hints at the idea that 'explorative' is only used for living beings. To be honest I don't think I've ever seen 'explorative' before, I made  my suggestion based on the fact that I've only seen 'exploratory' used for operations and questioning. The fact that Macquarie says that 'explorative' is mentioned as synonym of 'exploratory' suggests that it is, pretty much, an exact synonym,

Comment: @BoldBen: (a) The sentence "The second meaning in Macquarie seems useful to describe _living beings_ (or possibly _animate objects_)." in my question hints at that idea. This is inherited from 'inclined to', which to my knowledge only is used in relation to living beings. (b) Does Macquarie really list them as synonyms? Again, from my question: "I also am not sure whether the crucial 'Also, **explorative**.' at the end concerns both meanings or just the second one."

Comment: @MårtenW Have you any support for your contention that 'explorative' is used exclusively for living creatures and animate objects whereas 'exploratory' is not? Not only that but non-sentient things like operations or investigations are carried out by sentient humans anyway or they wouldn't be exploratory. Only sentient creatures have volition. I still don't see the distinction.

Comment: @BoldBen: I am basing my thinking on the definitions given in Longman and (more importantly) Macquarie, but, as I have written, I am not sure about my interpretation. The second meaning in Macquarie uses 'inclined to', which to my knowledge is only used about living beings. In that case, it follows that the second meaning can only be used about living beings. Now, if the crucial 'Also, **explorative**.' at the end only covers the second meaning (which I am also not sure about), that would make 'explorative' only useful in relation to living beings.

Comment: @MårtenW The Macquarie entry you quote specifically says that the "inclined to make explorations" definition is a definition of 'exploratory' so I don't see where you get the difference from and, in most dictionaries I've seen, extra words added as 'also' at the end of an entry are given as alternatives to the word being defined, not just to one of the definitions. Sorry, can't agree with you, I think 'explorative' is an uncommon synonym for 'exploratory' and nothing else.